# i am trying to create a banking app and i am getting this error " Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$amount"

Tags: php, relationship, insert-update

user.php

```
public function transaction()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Activity\transactionModel::class);
}
```

transactionModel.php

```
class transactionModel extends Model
{
    protected $guarded=[];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: the error is not in this piece of code

Comment: You are probably doing `$user->transactions->amount`.  But which amount? There are many transactions for that user, it is a collection.  Googling your error turns up many solutions here on SO, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276064/laravel-hasmany-relationship-undefined-property-illuminate-database-eloquent-re

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel HasMany relationship Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276064/laravel-hasmany-relationship-undefined-property-illuminate-database-eloquent-re)

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in the code you have posted, but that error often comes from code like this:

```
$user->transaction()->amount;
```

Also, keep in mind that if a `user` HAS MANY `transactions` the method should be called `transactions`, not `transaction`, and with this nomenclature, you should see that you are trying to get the `amount` of multiple `transactions`, and so it has no sense

By the way, if you want the `transactions` of a user, you should use code like this

```
$user->transactions; // Collection of transactions
```

and not

```
$user->transactions(); // HasMany representing the relation
```